# How to get Object from MQTT message payload

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

On receiving mqtt message I am trying to get Object from payload (byte[])

```
Object ob = SerializationUtils.deserialize(message.getPayload());
```

I am getting:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B22736E
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:193)
```

Comment: How did you write the object in that message? It does not look like a serialized Java object.

Comment: A javascript is sending a JSON message that i am receing in java

Comment: Most likely this is then not a Java object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a JSON parser not the Apache Commons Serialization library.

Something like the [JSON.org](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) parser

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(msg.toString());
```